# How to see if anaconda is perfectly installed and running?

Tags: python, anaconda

I just downloaded the anaconda package, *Anaconda3-5.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg* ,

with(?) my *python-3.6.6-macosx10.9.pkg* . And when i run to see if it is installed, I check with the Terminal (bash?) and it says:

[picture of my shell and Terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD0YK.png)

Is it correct installed? And how do I know that Python and anaconda "connect" to each other?  Does it per automatic, or do I need to do something?

And I don't know if this matter, or if this is wrong or not, but the package says Anaconda3-5.2.0 ... But the terminal says condo 4.5.4. Wrong version??

Regards,

Comment: `conda` is a shell command, not a command to be typed into the python interpreter.

Comment: Try running `ipython notebook` in the terminal and see if a notebook instance gets opened in a browser. And try importing few packages such as pandas and numpy.

Comment: @jordanm python interpreter - what's that? the idle? *shy*

Comment: @prashanth yeah, I typed it and got to a new browser, but all i see there is like... Applications
Desktop 
Documents  etc etc.. and som jpg, rmd, html, txt.. but no packages.

Comment: Thats okay. Create a python notebook and run the commands `import pandas` and `import numpy`. If they run, then most probably everything is set.

Comment: @prashanth I got this : http://www.bilddump.se/bilder/20180927215311-213.89.175.7.png  " >>> " when i run numpy and pandas